# Strategy Not Making Trades

Tags: pine-script

This strategy makes trades in backtest and live on the chart, but for my paper trading account no trades are executed.

```
//@version=5
strategy('Heiken Ashi Price Action', overlay=true)

//Enter trade
if close > open and high > close and high - close > (open - low) * 3
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, 1)

if close < open and low < close and close - low > (high - open) * 3
    strategy.entry('short', strategy.short, 1)
```

Comment: How did you connect this strategy to your paper trading account?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Heiken Ashi candlesticks on your chart use estimated prices, not actual prices. Switch to regular candles and it will work again. I know, it sucks, I LOVE heiken ashi candles too. But, apparently they don't work well with pine strategies because pine works on ACTUAL ticks and heiken ashi candles just estimate the closes and opens of the price values.

Also, if that's not valid, you need your strategy.exit() call. You are only entering, but never exiting.